# Внедрение кода из dll

Tags: hook, delphi, dll

Сталкивался кто с внедрением длл из другой длл?
Сабж, есть длл(длл1) в ней сидит хук на запуск процесса(она приатачена сервисом ко всем программам), когда запускается приложение X - длл1 запускает его в суспенде, и пытается внедрить в него длл2, вот тут и возникает проблема, внедрения не происходит, при том если из exe пытаюсь запустить приложение X в суспенде, то приатачить длл - выходит(способ внедрения в длл1 и exe - одинаков).
Для внедрения использу MadCHook. и\или найденый в интернетах пример внедрения(и то и то из exe работает).

Кто что посоветовать может?

```
  CreateProcessNextW             : function (lpApplicationName: PWideChar; lpCommandLine: PWideChar;
       lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
       bInheritHandles: BOOL; dwCreationFlags: DWORD; lpEnvironment: Pointer;
       lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar; const lpStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
       var lpProcessInformation: TProcessInformation) : bool; stdcall;

function CallBackW(lpApplicationName: PWideChar; lpCommandLine: PWideChar;
  lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
  bInheritHandles: BOOL; dwCreationFlags: DWORD; lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar; const lpStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  var lpProcessInformation: TProcessInformation) : bool; stdcall;
begin
  if ExtractFileName(lpApplicationName)='Приложение X' then
  Begin
    result := CreateProcessNextW(lpApplicationName,lpCommandLine,lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes,bInheritHandles,CREATE_SUSPENDED,lpEnvironment,lpCurrentDirectory,lpStartupInfo,lpProcessInformation);
    InjectModule('Assist_IGM.dll',lpProcessInformation.dwProcessId);    //Иньекция моей dll
    ResumeThread(lpProcessInformation.hThread);
  end
  else result := CreateProcessNextW(lpApplicationName,lpCommandLine,lpProcessAttributes,lpThreadAttributes,bInheritHandles,dwCreationFlags,lpEnvironment,lpCurrentDirectory,lpStartupInfo,lpProcessInformation);
end;

begin
  HookAPI( kernel32, 'CreateProcessW', @CallBackW, @CreateProcessNextW);
end.
```

Comment: Внедрение? То есть код из одной dll копируется в память/файл другой dll? Ужас.

Comment: Одна длл копирует вторую длл в запускаемый ехе файл)

Comment: пы.сы есть другие варианты поставить хук на запуск приложения(некого) и внедрять длл только в него?(DX оверлей для некого приложения :)

Answer (score 1):

Загрузка библиотеки в память процесса происходит так: Если указанный модуль (библиотека) еще не загружена для вызывающего приложения (*хук на запуск процесса*), система вызывает из библиотеки функцию `DllMain` (код между главными `begin` и `end` в библиотеке). Это, судя по всему, и есть ваш хук. **Существуют ограничения** на действия, которые можно делать в `DllMain`. Читаем [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[На картинке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) видно, что происходит перед выполнением `DllMain` и после.

[Чуть ниже картинки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#general_best_practices) написано, что **нельзя** делать в `DllMain`: **создавать процессы**, потоки, загружать библиотеки, выходить из потока и т.д. Там большой список. По этому из библиотеки *внедрения не происходит*.

Чтобы обойти эти ограничения, вам нужно свой код вынести из `DllMain` в экспортируемую функцию (см. справку по ключевому слову `exports`).

Answer (score 0):

Тут, правда, на C++, но все равно должны разобраться: http://habrahabr.ru/post/168255/

Comment: Не то) интересует не само внедрение длл из exe, а внедрение длл из длл!!(коментарий под вопросом).

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать поискать модуль и описание `advApiHook.pas`
Делал я подобное, только немного по-другому. Из приаттаченой либы запускал другое приложение с приаттаченной второй либой.

Кода не дам - на дельфи не пишу уже несколько лет.

Comment: Либу видел, не пашет если пытатся из одной либы(уже внедренной) внедрять другую.

Comment: Значит, как-то не так внедряете. Может внедрить как в своего пациента, так и в сторонний процесс. Кода под рукой нету, через пару недель доберусь до рабочей станции - попробую поискать, если нужда ещё не отпадет.

Comment: Да и разница-то какая откуда внедрять? И у обычного приложения, которое внедряет либу кому-то, и у внедренной либы имеется своё пространство памяти, свои потоки, свои разрешения. Для ОС приложение и либа отличаются только тем, что приложение использует как базовое пространство памяти ОС, а либа - пространство памяти своего пациента. Больше ограничений нет.